# DOMPDF not formatting PDF output on live server

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

I have a script that generates a pdf file using DOMPDF. Locally it generates fine the way I want it to be but online, the formatting is scattered. These are the two samples

[image: This s the well formatted picture from localhost] [image: This is the picture from the live server]

I am using PHP 5.3.x locally and online. I don't know what the problem is. Please could someone help

Comment: Any solutions? I have the same issue at the moment...

Answer (score 1):

I also gone through the same problem. Dompdf is perfectly working on localhost but not on live server. Actually my localhost is having php-version-5 and the server is running on php7.

So here's the solution:
just use dompdf-0.8.6 on server .

This worked for me.
you can download it from here : https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/archive/v0.8.6.zip

Answer (score 1):

My fix was to use asset to access my css file on live server, for example {{asset('css/style.css')}} and that fixed my issue, while on local server, what worked was using the public_path to access the css file, example {{public_path('css/style.css')}}

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue... **the problem is using custom fonts**.

Don't just try normal @fontface css embedding, use DomPDF's font loader and 'install' the font.

See link for usage for load_font.php : https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/UnicodeHowTo#use-the-load_fontphp-script-included-with-dompdf

Answer (score 0):

In my case (**v 0.7.0**), the problem was that I was missing some required libraries in the "lib" folder, namely:

- `php-font-lib`
- `php-svg-lib`

Both can be downloaded from Github, and then add 2 folders with the above names into the lib folder, where you should dump all the downloaded files.

Or, better yet, just use Composer next time! (this is a note to self)

Answer (score 0):

I've same problem and solved by deleting just a single file. The file which is under `'dompdf/lib/fonts/dompdf_font_family_cache.php'`

[You may get this answer better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51474704/dompdf-rendering-complete-html-in-1-line/51510822#51510822)