# dompdf rendering complete html in 1 line

Tags: rendering, dompdf

I have created pdf with simple p tags, table and img tags.
On live server its not working and on localhost its working well.
Please see both pdf files.
Can you please help me to fix this issue?
Thanks

https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/files/2218526/localhost.pdf
https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/files/2218527/livesite.pdf

Answer (score 3):

I've faced the same problem. I solved it..

You just need to delete a file `dompdf_font_family_cache.php`. You may found this file under `'dompdf/lib/fonts/'`
and let the renderer regenerate the cache.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Works !! What is the logic behind this ?

Comment: I know we are not supposed to say Thanks in comments but really thanks! I was looking for solution of this issue and couldn't find any. I think this works because the custom fonts you might have added aren't cached the DOMPDF and you have to delete this file so DOMPDF can regenerate that file and add the fonts that you use to it's directory.